# Jekyll serve Conversion error "No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, jekyll, rouge

I have followed the [installation instructions for Windows](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/), using the "rouge" syntax highlighter.

I created new site with "jekyll new" and changed to that folder. However, when I attempt to run "bundle exec jekyll serve" I get following error, which I have Googled fruitlessly.

```
    Generating...
     Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
     Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/main.scss':
     No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./.sass-cache/361b8f43efc4363cbd9a8a5cc41b098a7f33ed80/_syntax-highlighting.scssc20190809-21944-io0jgo
```

Have tried adding/removing following settings in _config.yml, changing their case etc...

```
highlighter: rouge
encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: Error does not occur when I use the [documentation theme for Jekyll](https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/index.html)

Comment: What's this file name? _syntax-highlighting.scssc20190809-21944-io0jgo

Comment: Try deleting the `.sass-cache` directory entirely. It will reappear the next time you build / serve the site locally.

Comment: Thanks, but deleting `.sass-cache` didn't help

Comment: full filepath given in the error message is ` ./.sass-cache/361b8f43efc4363cbd9a8a5cc41b098a7f33ed80/_syntax-highlighting.scssc20190812-28712-nbibpj`

Comment: Please try to run `jekyll clean` and `jekyll run`. I have tried to reproduce the behavior and was not able to do so. I am on windows 10, ruby 2.6.3, jekyll 4.0.0 and used the default theme without any issue.

Comment: I have used that for another test: https://github.com/mdo/jekyll-example, the only thing I needed to change was `relative_permalinks: false` in the _config.yml in this example project no further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests and I am not able to see this issue on Windows 10.

Follow the readme shown on the [Minima Theme Github page](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) to get this running. If the problem continues I'd suggest to raise an issue in the [Issue page of the Minima theme repository on Github](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues).